# Page title module fallback problem

Tags: 7

I'm using the [Page Title module](http://drupal.org/project/page_title) to set the `<title>` tags on nodes, etc.
I'm using the **[current-page:page-title]** token in my patterns.

According to the [manual](http://drupal.org/node/254771), this should let me write a custom page title on node level.

> This allows some nodes to 'inherit' the title from the node title and other nodes have the option to override the [page-title] token.
>   [...] in this case, the author could override the node title and provide a separate page title [...]. Note that this field does not allow the admin to completely override the Page Title, but just the [page-title] token, which will be inserted as normal into the Pattern for that node type.

And the manual also says:

> So, basically, if you use the [page-title] (**or [current-page:page-title] in Drupal 7**) token in the patterns/template settings, it will take it's value in the following order:
>
> 1. the value of the "Page Title" field.
> 2. the Entity Title (eg, Node Title, User Name or Term Name), if Page
>      Title field has no value (in 1).
> 3. the value of the title returned by Drupal's "get title" system (i.e. a fallback). This is usually defined by the Menu API system.

However, when the pattern is set to **[current-page:page-title]** and I do NOT write anything in the Page Title feed on node level. Then the node gets no title at all. It doesn't fall back to the pattern: It simply doesn't get any title.

Have I misunderstood anything?

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose a specific token context from those available such as [current-page-what?]:

```
[current-page-number]   The page number of the current page when viewing     paged lists.
[current-page-path] The URL alias of the current page.
[current-page-path-raw] The URL alias of the current page. Warning: Token value contains raw user input.
[current-page-title]    The title of the current page.
[current-page-url]  The URL of the current page.
```

You should specify your fallback global page titles under '/admin/settings/page-title' and for specific node types, such as 'story' 'page' or 'blog' for example.

You should input the page title tokens as follows;

```
Example 1:  [current-page-path] [page-title]
Example 2:  [page-title] | [site-name]
Example 3:  [page-title] | [site-slogan] - mysite.com
```

Note that you can insert symbols or text between the tokens or after.  In this case we've inserted the vertical bar '|' and a hyphen '-' plus the site name 'mysite.com' within the pattern.

I think you've understood correctly.

Although the example above relates to Drupal6, I've tried to recreate your problem in Drupal7 and can't because the default [current-page:page-title] | [site:name] always kicks in, as it should.

Have you tried completely removing the Page-Title module, running Cron, updating the database and installing the module again?